# Groupby Dataframe to Json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following df within 4 periods columns:

```
Customer|1|2|3|4|1|2|3|4
x       |5|5|-|-|N|E|C|-
.
.
.
```

The first 4 periods are the value paid by a customer, and the next 4 periods are the customer status. I only wrote one customer as example but there are plenty of them.

I want to export to JSON and now i'm using:

`df.unstack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().to_json()`

It's ok, but I'd like to get the json in this format, for instance:

`[{4: {‘E’: 17,‘C’: 18,‘N’:386}}]...`

the values are random, just to show the format: basically a dict of the status inside a dict of the period.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your code so we can try to help you?

Comment: thank you and sorry, but I found the answer, anywa. gotta cancel the question
it is:
df_results.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).to_json()